# Stuck on difficult Excel formula

Tags: excel, sumproduct

I am looking for help with a sumproduct function that I cannot seem to figure out.

In the Total Revenue column(column C) I want to write a sumproduct(or any other suggestions) formula to multiply New Customers in Week 3(20,000) by Week 0 Retention(100%) and then also Week 0 Revenue/Week($0.12).

I am looking to use a sumproduct formula because I want to start adding all the cohort revenue together as I go down the spreadsheet. I am currently using the formula below but its getting the wrong output in cell C7. I thought it would yield $2400 for total revenue by multiplying 20,000 customers by 100% retention by $0.12 Revenue per week but instead its using the incorrect revenue per week cell. Instead of using L4 the formula is using L7.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(F$4:F7,SORT(I$4:I7),SORT(L$4:L7))
```

[image]

Comment: So, you want every row of column C to be based on the customers for that row but the retention and revenue from row 4?  And ignore the other retention and revenue figures?  Then why is the SORT in there?

Comment: @TimRoberts - effectively yes. For example, in week 4(cell c8) I would want the sum of the week 3 cohort(20,000 x 36% * $0.13) and week 4 cohort(20,000 X 100% X $0.12). Think of the new customers column as a cohort of customers. Some will be retained each week but there would be churn as well. Hope that clarifies

Comment: Aha, so the columns are not really related to the rows at all.  Row 8 should be F8 x I4 x L4 plus F7 x I5 x L5 plus F6 x I6 x L6 plus F5 x I7 x L7, or $3,336.  So C8 depends an ALL the rows of F.  You probably need to create a VBA function for this.  You could premultiply columns I and L.

Comment: The following formula actually works in google sheets but I cannot figure out how to translate that to an excel formula: =SUMPRODUCT(F$4:F4, SORT(I$4:I4, ROW(I$4:I4), FALSE), SORT(L$4:L4, ROW(L$4:L4), FALSE))

Comment: The function should work in Excel.  It doesn't work in LibreOffice Calc, because Calc doesn't have a SORT funciton, but Excel does.  What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [array formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d) in cell C4:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS($C$4:C4)))+(COLUMN(INDIRECT("RC1:RC"&ROWS($C$4:C4),FALSE))-1)=ROWS($C$4:C4))*1,$F$4:F4* TRANSPOSE($I$4:I4)*TRANSPOSE($L$4:L4))
```

Remember to confirm it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Here an example of the two arrays whose product is sum to obtain the result in cell C8 (formulas are not the same for reproducibility's sake):

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0,12 | 0,13 | 0,14 | 0,15 | 0,16 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 0,36 | 0,311 | 0,269 | 0,232 |
| =(ROWS($A$3:A3)+(COLUMNS($A$3:A3)-1)=5)*1 | =(ROWS($A$3:B3)+(COLUMNS($A$3:B3)-1)=5)*1 | =(ROWS($A$3:C3)+(COLUMNS($A$3:C3)-1)=5)*1 | =(ROWS($A$3:D3)+(COLUMNS($A$3:D3)-1)=5)*1 | =(ROWS($A$3:E3)+(COLUMNS($A$3:E3)-1)=5)*1 |  | 0 | `=$G3*H$2*H$1` | `=$G3*I$2*I$1` | `=$G3*J$2*J$1` | `=$G3*K$2*K$1` | `=$G3*L$2*L$1` |
| =(ROWS($A$3:A4)+(COLUMNS($A$3:A4)-1)=5)*1 | =(ROWS($A$3:B4)+(COLUMNS($A$3:B4)-1)=5)*1 | =(ROWS($A$3:C4)+(COLUMNS($A$3:C4)-1)=5)*1 | =(ROWS($A$3:D4)+(COLUMNS($A$3:D4)-1)=5)*1 | =(ROWS($A$3:E4)+(COLUMNS($A$3:E4)-1)=5)*1 |  | 0 | `=$G4*H$2*H$1` | `=$G4*I$2*I$1` | `=$G4*J$2*J$1` | `=$G4*K$2*K$1` | `=$G4*L$2*L$1` |
| =(ROWS($A$3:A5)+(COLUMNS($A$3:A5)-1)=5)*1 | =(ROWS($A$3:B5)+(COLUMNS($A$3:B5)-1)=5)*1 | =(ROWS($A$3:C5)+(COLUMNS($A$3:C5)-1)=5)*1 | =(ROWS($A$3:D5)+(COLUMNS($A$3:D5)-1)=5)*1 | =(ROWS($A$3:E5)+(COLUMNS($A$3:E5)-1)=5)*1 |  | 0 | `=$G5*H$2*H$1` | `=$G5*I$2*I$1` | `=$G5*J$2*J$1` | `=$G5*K$2*K$1` | `=$G5*L$2*L$1` |
| =(ROWS($A$3:A6)+(COLUMNS($A$3:A6)-1)=5)*1 | =(ROWS($A$3:B6)+(COLUMNS($A$3:B6)-1)=5)*1 | =(ROWS($A$3:C6)+(COLUMNS($A$3:C6)-1)=5)*1 | =(ROWS($A$3:D6)+(COLUMNS($A$3:D6)-1)=5)*1 | =(ROWS($A$3:E6)+(COLUMNS($A$3:E6)-1)=5)*1 |  | 20000 | `=$G6*H$2*H$1` | `=$G6*I$2*I$1` | `=$G6*J$2*J$1` | `=$G6*K$2*K$1` | `=$G6*L$2*L$1` |
| =(ROWS($A$3:A7)+(COLUMNS($A$3:A7)-1)=5)*1 | =(ROWS($A$3:B7)+(COLUMNS($A$3:B7)-1)=5)*1 | =(ROWS($A$3:C7)+(COLUMNS($A$3:C7)-1)=5)*1 | =(ROWS($A$3:D7)+(COLUMNS($A$3:D7)-1)=5)*1 | =(ROWS($A$3:E7)+(COLUMNS($A$3:E7)-1)=5)*1 |  | 20000 | `=$G7*H$2*H$1` | `=$G7*I$2*I$1` | `=$G7*J$2*J$1` | `=$G7*K$2*K$1` | `=$G7*L$2*L$1` |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| =SUMPRODUCT(A3:E7,H3:L7) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Copy and paste it in a new sheet. The first array is an array that will have 0 in each cell but those in the bottom-right/top-left diagonal. This will allow for the multiplication of the last "New Costumers" value with the first "Retention" and "Revenue/Week" value, the second last with the second, the third last with the third and so on. The second array is simply a matrix with the multiplied values of each columns.